# Change ImagePicker from "Use Photo" to "Save Photo

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a part in my app in which users can take a quick photo and save it to the camera roll. My only is that after the photo has been taken, it comes to the screen with the square cropper (i guess that's what it is) and then down the bottom it says "Retake" and "Use Photo". I want that Use Photo to say "Save Photo" (which is what it does anyway). Is there anyway to do this?
Here's my code

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(chosenImage, nil, nil, nil);
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: No, there is no way to change the title of the button.

Comment: Is there any workaround? Also, is there any way to get rid of the square crop thing or whatever it is? to just take a full photo?

Comment: Perhaps using your own camera view overlay and your own "retake/save" screen instead of enabling the `allowsEditing` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**U can change cancel button to any title u want:**

1. Add **UINavigationControllerDelegate** delegate to your viewController that u will click the button and will show the camera
2. Add the below codes in your viewController:

   ```
   - (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
   [self changeCancelToAnythingUWantOf:viewController andReplacementString:@"Your Replacement String"];
   ```

   }

   ```
   - (void)changeCancelToAnythingUWantOf:(UIViewController*)vc andReplacementString:(NSString*)title {

   for(UIView *subView in vc.view.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
       UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)subView;
       if([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) {
           [btn setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
           break;
       }
   }

    if (subView.subviews) {
       for (UIView *subSubView in subView.subviews) {
           if ([subSubView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
               UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)subSubView;
               if([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) {
                   [btn setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                   break;
               } 
           }

           if (subSubView.subviews) {
               for (UIView *subSubSubView in subSubView.subviews) {
                   if ([subSubSubView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
                       UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)subSubSubView;
                       if([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) {
                           [btn setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                           break;
                       } 
                   }
               }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: This wouldn't work for changing the "Use Photo" button text, since it's not in these views. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: So, do not use default camera controls and please download that sample code : (This sample code of apple might have what u looking for) [SAMPLE CODE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can find this with recusrion way

```
func buttonWithTitle(forView view: UIView, title: String) -> UIButton? {
    guard view.subviews.count > 0 else { return nil }
    var needButton: UIButton? = nil
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if subview is UIButton {
            let button = subview as! UIButton
            if button.titleLabel?.text == title {
                return button
            }
        }

        needButton = buttonWithTitle(forView: subview, title: title)
        if needButton != nil { return needButton }
    }

    return needButton
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## First swizzling Bundle

```swift
private func swizzle(_ bundle: Bundle.Type) {

    [(#selector(bundle.localizedString(forKey:value:table:)),
      #selector(bundle.rd_localizedString(forKey:value:table:)))]
        .forEach { original, swizzled in

            guard let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(bundle, original),
                let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(bundle, swizzled) else { return }

            let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(
                bundle,
                original,
                method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod)
            )

            if didAddMethod {
                class_replaceMethod(
                    bundle,
                    swizzled,
                    method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                    method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod)
                )
            } else {
                method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
            }
    }
}

private var hasSwizzled = false

extension Bundle {
    final public class func
        doBadSwizzleStuff() {
        guard !hasSwizzled else { return }

        hasSwizzled = true
        swizzle(self)

    }

    @objc internal func rd_localizedString(forKey: String, value: String?, table: String?) -> String {
        let bundle = Bundle.main
        return bundle.rd_localizedString(forKey: forKey, value: value, table: table)
    }
}
```

## Second create localized strings for UIImagePickerController

Below content of mentioned files with keys I've seen (with standard english values), they are pretty self explaining

#### CameraUI.strings

```
"PHOTO" = "PHOTO";
"AEAF_LOCK_TEXT" = "AE/AF LOCK";
"API_CANCEL_TITLE" = "Cancel";
"HDR_AUTO" = "Auto";
"HDR_ON" = "On";
"HDR_OFF" = "Off";
"TIMER_OFF_TEXT" = "Off";
"USE_PHOTO" = "Use Photo";
```

#### PhotoLibraryServices.strings

```
"PHOTOS" = "Photos";
"CAMERA_ROLL" = "Camera roll";
"ALL_SCREENSHOTS" = "Screenshots";
```

#### PhotoLibrary.strings

```
"CANCEL" = "Cancel";
"RETAKE" = "Retake";
"STREAM_SHARED_BY_ME_SUBTITLE" = "From You";
"STREAM_SHARED_BY_SUBTITLE" = "From %@";
"ALBUM_IMAGE_COUNT_FORMAT" = "%@ Photos";
"ALBUM_VIDEO_COUNT_FORMAT" = "%@ Videos";
"1_ALBUM_PHOTO" = "1 Photo";
"1_ALBUM_VIDEO" = "1 Video";
"ALBUM_TWO_TYPES_LABEL_COMMAS" = "%@, %@";
```

#### PhotosUI.strings

```
"ALL_PHOTOS_IN_LIBRARY" = "Moments";
"PXUserCollectionsSectionTitle" = "My Albums";
"FULL_PHOTOS_GRID_ZOOM_LEVEL_TITLE" = "Moments";
"NO_PHOTOS_OR_VIDEOS" = "No Photos or Videos";
```

## Third implement your localization class

```
internal enum L10n {
  internal enum CameraUI {
    /// AE/AF LOCK
    internal static let aeafLockText = L10n.tr("CameraUI", "AEAF_LOCK_TEXT")
    /// Cancel
    internal static let apiCancelTitle = L10n.tr("CameraUI", "API_CANCEL_TITLE")
    /// Auto
    internal static let hdrAuto = L10n.tr("CameraUI", "HDR_AUTO")
    /// Off
    internal static let hdrOff = L10n.tr("CameraUI", "HDR_OFF")
    /// On
    internal static let hdrOn = L10n.tr("CameraUI", "HDR_ON")
    /// PHOTO
    internal static let photo = L10n.tr("CameraUI", "PHOTO")
    /// Off
    internal static let timerOffText = L10n.tr("CameraUI", "TIMER_OFF_TEXT")
    /// Use test
    internal static let usePhoto = L10n.tr("CameraUI", "USE_PHOTO")
  }

    // MARK: - Implementation Details

extension L10n {
  private static func tr(_ table: String, _ key: String, _ args: CVarArg...) -> String {
    // swiftlint:disable:next nslocalizedstring_key
    let format = NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: table, bundle: Bundle(for: BundleToken.self), comment: "")
    return String(format: format, locale: Locale.current, arguments: args)
  }
}

private final class BundleToken {}
```